# aspectj pointcut/advice only works with *

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm having some trouble getting my aspects to work correctly. For some reason they seem to only be working when I am really generic about where the aspect is applied. Out of the four pointcut/advice only the last matches and outputs anything. What am I missing here?

```java
public aspect VerboseAspect
{
    after(Game game) returning:
            call(* Game.addPlayer(Player))
            && target(game) {
        System.out.println("addPlayer(Player): player has been added");
    }

    after(Game game) returning:
            call(* Game.addPlayer(..))
            && target(game) {
        System.out.println("addPlayer(..): player has been added");
    }

    after(Game game) returning:
            call(* Game.*(Player))
            && target(game) {
        System.out.println("*(Player):player has been added");
    }

    after(Game game) returning:
            call(* Game.*(..))
            && target(game) {
        System.out.println("*(..):player has been added");
    }
}
```

Java class:

```java
public class Game {
    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        System.out.println("inside class");
        this.players.add(player);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
inside class
*(..):player has been added
```

Answer (score 0):

(Comment, but too long.)

What version of AspectJ are you using? How are you building? Ant? Maven? Other?

It works fine for me inside IntelliJ; running this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game g = new Game();
    g.addPlayer(new Player());
}
```

Produces:

```
inside class
addPlayer(Player): player has been added
addPlayer(..): player has been added
*(Player):player has been added
*(..):player has been added
```

Comment: I'm using 1.7 and I'm using IntelliJ to build it. I'd guess I don't have something configured correctly, but isn't the fact that one of them is working telling that it is compiling with ajc and reading teh aspect?

Comment: It must be something with my project, because I made a new project and just had a Game, Player and my aspect, and it worked fine. Poop.